# POSTing variable with an array within it

Tags: php, html

As the title says

```
$champion = array();
for($i=1;$i<=$champ_number; $i++){
                    $champion[$i] = $_POST['champno'.$i];
}
echo '<input type="hidden" name="champion[]" value="'.$champion.'">';
```

What's the simplest least secure way to POST this variable $champion through POST is?

Comment: I would suggest you to make hidden fields with corresponding name and value inside the loop itself and keepone more hidden field outside the loop to keep the count of `i`..all these will be posted to the next page and there you can get all the values using a for loop..try it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to follow this simple format:

**E.g. : FORM**

```
 <form method="post" action="submit.php">  
    <?php 
    $champion=array('hiii','helloooo');

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="champion" value="'.htmlspecialchars(json_encode($champion)).'">';


    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="sub">
    </form>
```

**your submit.php :**

```
<?php 
$champions = json_decode($_POST['champion'], true);
echo $champions[1];// out put helloooo
?>
```

Comment: $champion = array("test", "test2");
$championSerialized = json_encode($champion);
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="champion" value="'.$championSerialized.'">';

Tried it


$champion = json_decode($_POST['champion'], true);
    echo $champion[0];
      echo $champion[1];

Comment: You must use `htmlspecialchars` in your `$championSerialized` data.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to post the entire array, then: serializing your array. http://php.net/manual/de/function.serialize.php

```
...
$championSerialized = serialize( $champion );
echo '<input type="hidden" name="champion" value="' . $championSerialized . '">';
```

Retrieving the data is just using `$championPost = deserialize( $_POST[ 'champion' ] );`

Comment: I tried something like that 
     $championSerialized = serialize($champion);
     echo '<input type="hidden" name="champion" value="'.$championSerialized.'">'; and on the next page 
     $champion = unserialize($_POST['champion']);

Comment: Unserializing user-supplied data is a bad idea.